# Move files from one SharePoint to another SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, move

I have a Ticket List with many Form Items (20k) and i would like to move most of them to another SharePoint Site which is only used to archive those old items. We already have a Script that moves Items between Lists, so I modified it and came out with this.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$destinationUrl = "http://archiv/Archiv/IT%20Archiv/Helpdesk%202018"
$archivMaxID = 0
$moveItemCount = 0
$date = get-date("31.12.2018")
$startdate = get-date ("01.01.2018")

$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Helpdesk")
$archivweb = Get-SPWeb http://archiv
$archivList = $archivweb.Lists.TryGetList("Archiv")

#Höchste ID aus der Archivliste laden
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>"
$query.RowLimit = 1

foreach ($item in $archivList.GetItems($query))
{
    $archivMaxID = $item.ID
}

#Dateien in das Archiv verschieben
$items = $list.GetItems() | Where-Object {($_['Status'] -eq "Abgeschlossen" -or $_['Status'] -eq "Abgelehnt") -and $_['Erstellt'] -lt $date -and $_['Erstellt'] -gt $startdate}

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $modified = $item["Geändert"]
    $modifiedBy = $item["Editor"]

    $file = $item.File
    try
    {
        $file.MoveTo($destinationUrl + $file.Name)
        $archivMaxID += 1
        $file.ListItemAllFields["Geändert"] = $modified
        $file.ListItemAllFields["Editor"] = $modifiedBy
        $file.ListItemAllFields.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
        $moveItemCount += 1
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host "Datei $($item.Title) konnte nicht verschoben werden"
    }
}

Write-Host "$moveItemCount Einträge in das Archiv verschoben" -ForegroundColor Green

$web.Dispose()
```

When running it says the items could not be moved.

Is this even possible?  Do I have to move items to a new list on the same SharePoint and then with explorer move them to the archive SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Surely its possible to move files or List items from One SharePoint Site collection to another.

You can use [SharePoint-pnp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) PowerShell module to achieve the movement of files.

`Move-PnPFile -SiteRelativeUrl Documents/company.aspx -TargetUrl /sites/otherproject/Documents/company.docx`

Working Code using [SharePoint PnP online Copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/copy-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) command

```
#Powershell script to Copy files from one SharePoint Online Document Library folder to another
#Created By: Vinit Kumar

# Variable - Change the parameter as it need
$O365ServiceAccount="sharepointsiteadmin@abc.com"
$O365ServiceAccountPwd="password@123"
$SharePointSourceSiteURL="https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointDocumentationCentre/Teamsite" # Change this SharePOint Site URL
$SourceDocumentLIbraryName="Shared Documents";
$DestinationDocumentLIbraryNameRelativepath="/sites/SharePointDocumentationCentre/DestinationSite/Shared Documents/"

#Ends

[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $O365ServiceAccountPwd -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($O365ServiceAccount, $SecurePass) 
#Connecting to SharePointDocumentationCentre site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointSourceSiteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

# Get all files from Document Library
$Files=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $SourceDocumentLIbraryName -ItemType File
foreach($File in $Files)
{
$destinationPath=$DestinationDocumentLIbraryNameRelativepath+$File.Name;
$sourceURL=$SourceDocumentLIbraryName+"/" +$File.Name
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $sourceURL -TargetUrl $destinationPath -Force -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists
}
```

Keep in mind this doesn't "move" the file. This copies it to a new dir. Thus any existing links will not point to the new copy.